# Count the number of words using win32com

Tags: python, pywin32

I added some text in ms word document. Then I want to count the number of words. How to do that? My code is as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from time import sleep

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')

doc = word.Documents.Add()
word.Visible = True
sleep(1)

rng = doc.Range(0,0)
rng.InsertAfter('Can you tell me how many words are there in this sentence?')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client as win32
from time import sleep

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')

doc = word.Documents.Add()
word.Visible = True
sleep(1)

stri = 'Can you tell me how many words are there in this sentence?'
num = len([i for i in stri.split(" ")])

rng = doc.Range(0,0)
rng.InsertAfter(stri)

print("number of words : "+str(num))
```

Comment: Thank you Luca. However, I want to use the word counting function in WORD because my actual string is composed of different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code, you can paste the string in the clipboard to WORD. At the end, you get the clipboard result of the string appended with the number of words:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import win32api

shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
if shell.AppActivate('word') == False:
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Add()
    word.Visible = True
    shell.AppActivate('word')


shell.SendKeys("^{a}{BACKSPACE} ")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("^v")
shell.SendKeys("%{n}")
shell.SendKeys("{q}")
shell.SendKeys("{f}")
shell.SendKeys("numwords")
shell.SendKeys("~")
shell.SendKeys("^a^c")
```